# Images missing from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have been working on resolving a particular issue within my app for a few days now with no success. I have a `UIScrollView` which is used basically in the same way as the one in the App Store for displaying screenshots.

The problem I am having is that for some reason, only two images are being displayed (there should be five). I have confirmed that this isn't an issue with the images themselves, so it must be something to do with the code. Strangely, I actually have another `UIScrollView` in my app that does almost the exact same thing, but with three labels, and that works fine.

Here is my code:

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

```
    sixPlusImages = [
        UIImage(named: "Glance6Plus.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "Format6Plus.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "Swipe6Plus.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "Currencies6Plus.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "Search6Plus.png")!
    ]

    let pageCount = sixPlusImages.count

    for _ in 0..<pageCount {
        pageViews.append(nil)
    }

    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(sixPlusImages.count), height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    loadVisiblePages()
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageViews.count {
        return
    }

    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        return
    } else {
        var frame =  scrollView.frame //CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: scrollView.bounds.height)
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0

        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: sixPlusImages[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = frame
        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)

        pageViews[page] = newPageView
    }
}

func loadVisiblePages() {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

    let firstPage = page - 1
    let lastPage = page + 1

    for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    for index in firstPage...lastPage {
        loadPage(index)
    }

    for var index = lastPage+1; index < sixPlusImages.count; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadVisiblePages()
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= sixPlusImages.count {
        return
    }

    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }
}
```

So like I say, the first two images are being displayed, but the other three are just blank pages.

Anyone see any issues?

Comment: Have you tried adding any breakpoints or log statements to see where things are going wrong?  For example, is loadPage ever called for your missing images?  

As an aside, it's better to do the image loading in a "lazy" fashion (only if they are actually viewed/scrolled to) rather than loading the entire array up front.

Comment: I'm confused about why you aren't using `UITableView` for this - it handles most of this stuff for you.

Comment: @RehcsifMit I've just added a `println()` to loadPage and it's only being called three times for some reason. It passed the else twice, so that's why only two images are being loaded.

Comment: @AaronBrager The `UIScrollView` is within a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: You can put `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` instances inside of table view cells.

Comment: @RehcsifMit I've figured out the issue. `scrollViewDidScroll()` is only being called once, when the view appears. It is not being called each time the `UIScrollView` is scrolled, as it should be. Any ideas?

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll() is a delegate method.  Are you sure it's getting called at all, or is loadVisiblePages() only getting invoked via awakeFromNib()?  

If it's not getting called at all, make sure you're setting up the delegate properly.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems to be called only through `awakeFromNib()`. I have set the delegate for the `scrollView` as the view controller if that's what you mean?

Comment: @RehcsifMit Aha! I didn't realise that the delegate was supposed to be set as the cell rather than the table view! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having this same exact problem. Only two images appear.

Comment: I'm probably doing the same tutorial you were from Ray Winderlich. I can't get it to work with 5 images. Only two load.

Comment: I fixed it, had to add the delegate reference at the top of the class and then right click drag from the scrollview to the view controller and click delegate in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Add UIScrollViewDelegate to the class:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

}
```

Then in the storyboard, be sure to right click/drag from the scroll view to the view controller, click delegate.